# I need the Ember equivalent of jQuery's .ready.. FOR EVERY PAGE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I know that there are several questions on this, and several answers that people say worked for them, but the answers all don't work for me, the posters posting the answers don't tell which file to put the code snippets in (there are dozens of places it could go), and I can't comment asking if they could be more specific because I don't have 50 reputation.

I want the code to run:

1. On every page reload
2. AFTER everything is loaded

Actually two methods. One that doesn't fire on transitions (ie `this.transitionTo()`) and one that does.

and I need to know exactly where to put the code, what file, where and in what way.

I have read about init functions and afterRender hooks but none work because the answers do not clarify where to put the code.

Comment: Basically thats not possible. The programmer can always load more data. There is no way to know everything is loaded. Maybe you can clarify *why* you need this, and we can suggest you a solution?

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Can you say explain what you're trying to accomplish?  Ember is a SPA (Single-page application) so concepts like "page reload" and "everything is loaded" are somewhat vague.

Comment: When I tend to say what I'm trying to do, people tend to give me opinions on the way they think I should do it and it does not answer the original question. Pretty much my conclusion is ember sucks if you can't do an equivalent of jQuery's .ready() function. And just my opinion of Ember is already pretty low. and if other frameworks are this way then I would ditch them in favor of just straight js development tbh.

Comment: Now what I'm trying to do is run a function to give unique IDs to elements after the page has rendered everything. In normal client-side scripting it would be a simply jQuery $().ready() ... but Ember has to make everything super difficult. And honestly it's not Ember itself. it's the fact that I cannot find ANY ANSWERS on how to do basic things. I've written more quetsions in Stack Overflow since working with Ember than I have in my entire life as a web developer.

Comment: @AlexanderRose any reason you want to give unique id's to ALL elements? just so you know, ember does give unique id's to every element it renders. Also, if you want to give a manual id to any element, you can easily do that in your .hbs file (the template) - just like any html page. I am ignoring your rants for now because I was like you when I started ember and I know how frustrating it can be. But in all honesty, frameworks like Ember or React are the future, whether you like it or not :) it does makes things simpler, and gives me a lot of power to create powerful apps

Comment: @AlexanderRose- yes, I see out of your 9 posts over the last 3 years, you asked 3 Ember questions.  Sorry you're having such a bad experience with Ember.  It is often difficult to think outside of our preconceived notions of how a web framework should work.  I agree many modern frameworks have a steep learning curve.  I hope you can stick with it and everything will "click" for you.  I highly recommend thoroughly reading the [Ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com)

Comment: It's really not Ember that is the problem, it's the documentation. Like I search "ember views" and the #1 on the SERP is Stack Overflow and NOT the official Ember website. This is very telling. So the reason why I want to get the IDs is because it's needed for our QA guys to do automated testing. This seems to be a common thing among testing/QA and would only be in our QA environment and not others.

Comment: Then 3-4 links down from the Stack Overflow page is the Ember Views official documentation which has NO TEXT other than telling the functions etc. API with absolutely no actual documentation whatsoever, and it says it's depracated but doesn't say why, doesn't say what you should use instead, doesn't say ANYTHING. Look at PHP docs. It says "Depracated, use XYZ instead" .. and it's a link to that doc page. The learning curve isn't steep. The docs suck. When I'm able to find pages that explain it properly it's as easy as jQuery to work with.

Comment: Deprecation guides https://emberjs.com/deprecations/ and https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/ and https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `didTransition()` is what I want to do this. It has to be in the actions of the route, like so:

```
actions:{
    didTransition(){
        Ember.run.later('afterRender', () => {
            // do stuff here
            }); 
        }, 500);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This will run every time the route is transitioned to.

Answer (score 0):

"I have read about init functions and afterRender hooks but none work because the answers do not clarify where to put the code" -- this will be in the route/component. If you want a piece of code to run after render of every route, you will put this code in every route, under afterRender. (You can possibly have a helper function for this, to keep your code DRY)

If you want to not make it happen on transition, you will have to make the route know that it is being entered by transition from another route, and for that you will have to send in a parameter when calling this.transitionTo(). Use this variable as a flag to either run that piece of code or not.

Comment: I have used several of these hooks and it seems that whenever I change something like go to a different sub route or something it stops working. I will add an event listener for example `Ember.$('input').on('change', function() { console.log('test'); }` and it works UNTIL I CLICK ANYTHING, then it stops working FOREVER. This has to work ALL THE TIME because I need to hook something when my form elements change or when basically 500,000 other things happen that would be coded in 20 !@#&!@#^ minutes if I wasn't using Ember I've spend 3 days trying to figure out to no avail reading EVERY guide.

Comment: the hooks on a component/route/controller would work for only that component/route/controller -- the dom is destroyed on changing it to a different page. try to resist the frustration and go one question at a time! :)

Comment: also, what is it exactly that you're trying to accomplish? give as much detail as possible - you will find help